# Django with two __in queries slower than retrieving separate querysets

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, django-queryset

I have a reasonably complex database consisting of a model, `Bar` which may have several `Spam`s, implemented by a ForeignKey relationship (each `Spam` knows which `Bar` it belongs to). A further model, `Foo` has exactly two `Bars`. Here's the relevant bit of `models.py`:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    g = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Spam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lendth=20)
    val = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(bar)

class Foo(models.Model):
    bar1 = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='foo_bar_2')
    bar2 = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='foo_bar_1')
```

I'd like to know which `Foo` has a particular pair of `bar`s, where each is identified by its set of `Spams`. Getting the `bars` matching the two sets is fine and reasonably fast:

```
def get_bars_queryset(spam_tuples):
    bars = Bar.objects
    for name, val in spam_tuples:
        bars = bars.filter(spam__name=name, spam__val=val)
    return bars

    bars1 =  get_bars_queryset(spam_tuples=[('eggs', '5'), ('bacon', 'yes')])
    bars2 =  get_bars_queryset(spam_tuples=[('eggs', '1'), ('toast': '4'), ('milk', '2')])
```

But when I try the obvious way of retrieving the `Foo` I want:

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar1__in=bars1, bar2__in=bars2)
```

the performance is very bad. It turns out to be much quicker to retrieve the two sets of `Foo`s separately and find their union:

```
foos1 = Foo.objects.filter(bar1__in=bars1)
foos2 = Foo.objects.filter(bar2__in=bars2)

foo_bar1_ids = set(foos1.values_list('pk', flat=True))
foo_bar2_ids = set(foos2.values_list('pk', flat=True))
foo_id = foo_bar1_ids & foo_bar2_ids
foos = Foo.objects.filter(pk__in=foo_id)
```

I'm guessing this is because the native Django approach is not joining my tables efficiently. How can I force it to?

Comment: I think you can log the SQL of foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar1__in=bars1, bar2__in=bars2) by using foos.query then you can tuning your database to serve better for that query.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case it helps anyone else, the solution was to force evaluation of the `bar` querysets:

```
bars1 =  list(get_bars_queryset(spam_tuples=[('eggs', '5'), ('bacon', 'yes')]))
bars2 =  list(get_bars_queryset(spam_tuples=[('eggs', '1'), ('toast': '4'),
                                             ('milk', '2')]))
```

before filtering the `Foos` with

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar1__in=bars1, bar2__in=bars2)
```

This is hinted at in the documentation (Performance considerations): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in as particularly a problem for MySQL. Thanks to @Minh-Hung Nguyen for pointing me in thr right direction.